# Tweaking hover area for jQuery sliding boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using some jQuery to create 3 boxes that on hover, slide up to reveal more content. My two questions are:

1) How can I tweak it so only hovering on the gray box actually activates the slide instead of the entire invisible area above the gray box?

2) Is there a better way to accomplish this? I'm a beginner when it comes to JavaScript and hacked a few things I found in Google searches together. For example, it'd be nice for the height to be generated automatically based on the content instead of relying on a fixed height.

http://jsfiddle.net/kUjax/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.boxgrid.caption').hover(function(){
        $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'120px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
    }, function() {
        $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'210px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it yourself:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.boxgrid .boxcaption').hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({top: '120px'}, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 150
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({top: '210px'}, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 150
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kUjax/1/

Comment: Thanks! Any way to dynamically adjust the height (instead of a fixed height) of the opened box or would that require an entirely different approach?

Comment: Expand the height of .boxcaption dynamically so whatever content (in this case, the H3 and lorem ipsum) is inside of it, fits. Currently, it's height is fixed via CSS.